# .htaccess only redirect index.php to new site

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

We are working on our new site, and we want to make the homepage re-direct to a subdirectory I am wondering how to do this with .htaccess as then any other page they need to go back to the old site.

Comment: Why use `.htaccess` if you have full control over Apache?

Comment: what's the sub-folder? you need to redirect everything to the sub-folder?

Comment: what do you mean full control over Apache? and sub folder is newsite/

Comment: You should add some examples. It is not clear from the question what are you trying to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

These rules will forward `http://yourdomain.example.com` to `http://yourdomain.example.com/yoursubdir/`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?$ yoursubdir/ [L]
```

If you want, instead, to redirect an URL with `index.php` (like `http://yourdomain.example.com/index.php` use this rules instead.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index.php$ yoursubdir/ [L]
```

In general have a look at the documentation of mod_rewrite. There are many useful and free guides around the net.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this should do the trick

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/some/subdir/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will rewrite the requested URI to some/subdir of newdomain.com